# Choose to loop infinitely if a number equals 0 or loop until some number if that number is greater than 0 - Java

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I want to loop infinitely using a for loop if a number equals 0, and loop until that number number if the number is greater than 0. Here's the code to help visual what I'm getting at.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < this.getNumRounds(); i++) {
        // 30 some lines of code
    }
```

or

```
    for ( ; ; ) {
        // 30 some lines of code
    }
```

if `getNumRounds()` is greater than 0, do the first loop, if it equals 0, do the second. I would prefer to do this without copying and pasting my 30 some lines of code twice and using an if statement seeing as the code is redundant, though I could use a function to take out that redundancy, but I'm looking to see if there's another option.

Comment: I would just refactor the 30 lines into a function and use an if-else. It'll make the code much clearer. Code should be self-documenting, so if your description of the problem contains an "if-else" (as your description does), then the clearest way to translate that to code is using an if-else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the powerful ternary operator:

```
for (int i = 0; this.getNumRounds() == 0 ? true : i < this.getNumRounds(); i++) {
    // 30 some lines of code
}
```

As noted in the comments by yshavit, there is a shorter, cleaner way of expressing this:

```
for (int i = 0; this.getNumRounds() == 0 || i < this.getNumRounds(); i++) {
    // 30 some lines of code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using a while loop instead?

```
int i = 0;
while(i < this.getNumRounds() || this.getNumRounds() == 0) {
//some 30 lines code
i++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want something like this:

```
int num = //whatever your number equals
if (num == 0) {
    boolean running = true;
    while (running) {
        doLoop();
    }
} else {
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        doLoop();
    }
}

private void doLoop() {
    //some 30 lines of code
}
```

This code puts the contents of the loop in a separate method and checks if the number is equal to 0. If it is, the program runs the doLoop() method forever. Otherwise, it runs until i equals the number.

Answer (score 0):

While it would be better to just create a method and use an if-statement you could add an if statement inside the for-loop to decrease i every iteration. It would look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= this.getNumRounds(); i++) {
    if(this.getNumRounds() == 0){
        i--;
    }
    // 30 some lines of code
}
```

Notice I changed `i < this.getNumRounds()` to `i <= this.getNumRounds`. This way if the number of rounds is zero then the loop will be called.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following.

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.getNumRounds() || i == 0; ++i) {
    do {
        // 30 lines of code
    } while (this.getNumRounds() == 0);
}
```

If `getNumRounds` is non-trivial to compute, consider pulling it out of the loop and calling it only once.